# DBContext throwing A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed

Tags: c#, mysql, async-await, entity-framework-6

I'm getting the exception : A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context.

I'm suing await db.SaveChangesAsync(); and not sure why I'm getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp.NET
{
    internal class MyApp
    {

        AppDBContext db = new AppDBContext();
        public MyApp() { }

        public async Task RunApp()
        {

            try
            {
                    var records = db.SBAOs.Take(25).ToList();
                    Console.WriteLine(records.Count());
                    var allTasks = new List<Task<APIResult>>();

                    foreach (var record in records)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Adding {record.id}");
                        allTasks.Add(GetWebSite(record));
                    }

                    var results = await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);

                    Console.WriteLine("All finished");
                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        db.APIResults.Add(result);
                    }

                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                    Console.Write("All Done!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public async Task<APIResult> GetWebSite(SBAO record) 
        {

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var s = await client.GetStringAsync("https://dotnetfoundation.org");
                    record.Custom6 = record.OrderID;
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Finished {record.id} ");
                    var apiResult = new APIResult() { message = record.OrderID, SBAOId = record.id };
                    return apiResult;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error in thread{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    throw;
                }
                
            };

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the reason for `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` in `GetWebsite` method? You did not change anything. Remove that line and it should work

Comment: Unrelated: read the remarks section of HttpClient.

Comment: The error message says it all. Do not use a field for a DbContext. Create and dispose one when you need it.

Comment: This is occurring because you are using `WaitAll` to parallelize the task execution. To do this, each task needs its own `DbContext` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change your code something as following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp.NET
{ 
    internal class MyApp
    {
        HttpClient client = new ();
        
        public MyApp() { }

        public async Task RunApp()
        {
            try
            {
                using var context = new AppDBContext();
                var records = context.SBAOs.Take(25).ToList();
                Console.WriteLine(records.Count());
                var allTasks = new List<Task<APIResult>>();

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Adding {record.id}");
                    allTasks.Add(GetWebSite(record));
                }

                var results = await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);

                Console.WriteLine("All finished");
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    context.APIResults.Add(result);
                }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                Console.Write("All Done!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public async Task<APIResult> GetWebSite(SBAO record) 
        {

            using (AppDBContext context = new AppDBContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    var s = await client.GetStringAsync("https://dotnetfoundation.org");
                    record.Custom6 = record.OrderID;
                    context.Update(record);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Finished {record.id} ");
                    var apiResult = new APIResult() { message = record.OrderID, SBAOId = record.id };
                    return apiResult;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error in thread{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    throw;
                }
                
            };

        }

    }
}
```

You are getting the error because `DbContext` is not supposed to be used in multi-threading manner, also as mentioned in comments `HttpClient` should not  be created and disponed frequently.

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application